# Mongo multiple groups

Tags: mongodb

I have the following table:

```
{ _id:'',
  user_name: "test1"
  "date": "2014-01-30T10:14:50.004Z"
},
{ _id:'',
  user_name: "test2"
  date: "2014-01-17T15:48:20.420Z"
},
{ _id:'',
  user_name: "test3"
  date: "2014-01-24T18:07:14.627Z"
},
```

I need to get the number of records per month for each user, as in the example below:

```
{month:"01", "test1": 89, "test2":32, "test3":12},
{month:"02", "test1": 11, "test2":23, "test3":0}
```

number - count of records

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have your dates in ISODate format.

After that, you can use the [aggregate framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) to get the results in the format you wish.

You can get to an intermediate stage of the desired end result with the following:

```
db.c.aggregate([ 
{$project: {_id:0, user_name: "$user_name", month: { $month: "$date" } } },
{$group: {_id:{month:"$month", user_name:"$user_name"}, count: {$sum:1} } },
{$project: {_id:0, month: "$_id.dmonth", user_name:"$_id.user_name", count: "$count"  } }
])
```

To get the results in an array, you can append a *$group*, like so:

```
db.c.aggregate([ 
{$project: {_id:0, user_name: "$user_name", month: { $month: "$date" } } }, 
{$group: {_id:{month:"$month", user_name:"$user_name"}, count: {$sum:1} } }, 
{$project: {_id:0, month: "$_id.month", user_name:"$_id.user_name", count: "$count"  } },
{$group: { _id: "$month", results: { $addToSet: { user_name: "$user_name", count: "$count" } } } },
{$project: {_id:0, month: "$_id", results: "$results"}}
])
```

Comment: Jinxcat, thank you! is it possible to to group the data as in my example?

Comment: It is not particularly straight-forward... I doubt you have a small, finite number of user_names. If you know the particular values beforehand, you can use conditional sums. If they are infinite, then I am sorry, I am not aware of how to solve it. You could have them in a list though... {month:"01", results: [ {user_name: "test1", count: 89}, {},...]} is just one step away.

Comment: Added another $group to add them to array

Answer (score 0):

There is a very similar example for this scenario in the Mongo Aggregation [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/#return-usernames-ordered-by-join-month)

Comment: Saket, thank you for your reply, but i can't find similar example on this page.